# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling

I am using spring framework 3.2 with hibernate 4 , I get the above exception when sending a request after a long idle time on the local server ( apache-tomcat v7.0 ) and the database is located on remote server. After hours of search I came to that the problem comes from the connection pool. I tried number of connection pools but didn't find the satisfying solution. bellow is the current datasource on my spring-data file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
<property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="URL" value="${app.jdbc.url}" />
<property name="user" value="${app.jdbc.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}" />
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
<value>
MinLimit:70
MaxLimit:200
InitialLimit:20
ConnectionWaitTimeout:120
InactivityTimeout:180
ValidateConnection:true
</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

please advise.

Comment: Are you reusing the connection handle? Try getting a fresh connection handle

Comment: what is connection handle? and is it used with java? note: I'm using JDBC not ODBC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will get the "Invalid or Stale Connection" error when you have a connection in the connection pool which is no longer connected to the Database actively. Below are few scenarios which can lead to this

1. Connection is manually aborted from the database by a dba. For example, if
   the connection was killed using "ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION"
2. When a connection exists in the connection pool without being used for a
   long time and is disconnected due to the timeouts enforced by the
   database (idle_time)
3. A database restart
4. A network event has caused
   the connection to drop, probably because the network has become
   unavailable or a firewall has dropped a connection which has been
   open for too long.

If you are setting the `InactivityTimeout`, then you have to make sure that it's less that the `IDLE_TIME` enforced by the database. You can get the `IDLE_TIME` with the below query

```
select * from dba_profiles dp, dba_users du
where dp.profile = du.profile and du.username ='YOUR_JDBC_USER_NAME';
```

When you use connectionCacheProperties, always make sure that you set the `PropertyCheckInterval` property to something less than the timeouts. The default value is 900 seconds which means that the cache daemon thread will only run every 15 minutes and enforce the timeouts. So you would always want to set this to a value lower than your timeout properties.

I would always make sure that I use 0 as the MinLimit.

Rewriting you config file a little bit would make it :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="URL" value="${app.jdbc.url}" />
<property name="user" value="${app.jdbc.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}" />
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
   <props merge="default">
    <prop key="MinLimit">0</prop>
    <prop key="MaxLimit">200</prop>
    <prop key="InitialLimit">1</prop>
    <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">120</prop>
    <prop key="InactivityTimeout">180</prop>
    <prop key="ValidateConnection">true</prop>
    <prop key="PropertyCheckInterval">150</prop>
   </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

You might also get a "Invalid or Stale Connection Error" when your network is actually broken at the time when you try to validate an old connection obtained from the pool.

Answer (score 2):

`connectionCachingEnabled` is the key here. By setting it to true you are using implicit connection cache (kind of proprietary Oracle connection pooling) which caches the connection.
But with `ValidateConnection` the connection should have been validated. You mentioned you tried different connection pools. Almost all connection pools like ([commons dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [tomcat dbcp](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)) have this facility of validating connections before handing over to the application. For e.g., [Tomcat DBCP](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes) has property `testOnBorrow` along with `validationInterval` and `validationQuery`. Other pools too have similar property. With other pools too are you getting the same issue ?

Comment: thank you I removed the connectionCachingEnabled attribute and avoided that problem

Comment: Also please review the effect of this on performance as now the connection would not be cached. You might consider a full fledged connection pool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen the error

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache.
```

After switch to Oracle's ucp, I haven't seen any Stale connections since. I have setting like following.

```
<New id="DS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>OracleDS</Arg>
    <Arg>

    <New class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl">
                    <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.corp.com:1234:xyz</Set>
                    <Set name="user">owner</Set>
                    <Set name="password”>pwd</Set>
                    <Set name="connectionFactoryClassName">oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</Set>
                    <Set name="minPoolSize">0</Set>
                    <Set name="maxPoolSize">10</Set>
                    <Set name="inactiveConnectionTimeout">300</Set>
                    <Set name="maxStatements">200</Set>
                    <Set name="maxConnectionReuseCount">150</Set>
                    <Set name="connectionWaitTimeout">9</Set>
                    <Set name="abandonedConnectionTimeout">30</Set>
                    <Set name="validateConnectionOnBorrow">true</Set>
                    <Set name="SQLForValidateConnection">SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL</Set>
    </New>

    </Arg>
</New>
```