# Oracle stale connection

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

Every once in a while in my app I get this error:

```
ERROR 2015-04-09 08:30:13,724 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] mojo.jdbc.MojoAlertDataAccess: Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:421)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:395)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:179)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)
        at mojo.jdbc.MojoAlertDataAccess.getAllAlertTypes(MojoAlertDataAccess.java:807)
```

So currently I have a datasource in Spring defined as:

```
<bean id="globalDSRead" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
         <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
         <property name="URL" value="${mojo.jdbc.read.url}"/>
         <property name="user" value="${mojo.jdbc.read.username}"/>
         <property name="password" value="${mojo.jdbc.read.password}"/>
         <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
             <value>
                 PropertyCheckInterval:10
                 MinLimit:1
                 MaxLimit:200
                 InitialLimit:1
                 ConnectionWaitTimeout:30
                 InactivityTimeout:30
                 ValidateConnection:true
             </value>
         </property>
     </bean>
```

As far as I can tell this happens when the app has been sitting idle for a while, but it's not all together easy to reproduce.

Also - Another thing that occurs in this function is the retrieval of the connection can take a long time to come back, again this usually happens when the app's been sitting idle for a long time.

Anyone have any ideas whatcould be misconfigured?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a firewall between your application server and database server that could be dropping idle TCP connections after some period of time (an hour or so)?  Also see the top rated answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589694/java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-or-stale-connection-found-in-the-connection-cache

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen that before. I recommend to use Apache DBCP (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) for the connection pool management.